# Download File contents with Python Requests

Tags: python-requests, python-3.8

```
from threading import local
import requests
import urllib
import json
import wget

def login(mail, password):
    s = requests.Session()
    payload = {"userid": mail, "password": password}
    res = s.post("http://192.168.137.43/goform/chklogin?_t=1642949581416", json=payload)
    my_json = res.json()
    my_token = my_json["token"]
    cookies = {
        "Admin-Token": my_token,
        "token": my_token,
    }
    response = s.get(
        "http://192.168.137.43/goform/DownloadRecordForm?_t=1645541239944&userid=&from=&to=&order=desc&start=0&limit=15&type=csv",
        cookies=cookies,
    )

    text_file = open("data333.csv", "wb")
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        text_file.write(chunk)
    text_file.close()
    return s
```

Hi, I am trying to download an excel from specific website by using token but I got only a response code with excel file like "{"retvalue":0, code:"success", filename:""}". There is no contents and excel data that I want. How can I solve it?

Have a great day.

Comment: Can you get the excel file to download some other way? (say curl or another http client?)

Comment: so there is no way to download Excel Data with python requests module?

Comment: No, any file (That is present on the server, readable by the web-server, exposed to the internet by the webmaster, and you are authorized to access) can be downloaded. The type of file is immaterial

Comment: Then why I'm getting only response code without getting any file contents. Is there any errors with my code or do I need to add more?

Comment: I cannot tell, it is a local-network only resource.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me how to code the same with curl module base on my current coding?